# Timeline for scheduling in person interviews

Tags: interviewing

The company offered a time a week after they got back to me, but I'm unavailable at that time. What is the time frame for scheduling in person interviews? That is, how long can I push back the interview? One week? Maybe two?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regulations and agreements that are different for every company  and don't have universally applicable answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few factors here - from their side, it comes down to how many candidates are they considering and interviewing, and how much they want to consider you. You can't control their side, but don't forget, they have shortlisted you for interview, which means they already think you might fit the job.

From your side, the primary factor is why you can't make the invited time.

If it is because you are busy with work in your current position, and need to arrange some time off, then you might consider asking for a time just after normal business hours - there's a good chance they'll agree.

If you're travelling, then explain it to them, and ask for another appointment when you return.

If they don't agree in either scenario, then consider whether you want to work for a place that is not prepared to be flexible.

Answer (score 2):

There's no hard-and-fast rule about this, but I imagine that 2 weeks is quite long.

You really should make time within one week.

Otherwise it sends a message "I'm too busy for you guys!" Or "I can't really sacrifice too much for you"

Answer (score 2):

If they want you, they will want you.

When I had my interview for my current job, I was working at another job, I had my interview on the Friday and was planning on being late into work on the Friday for my other job to attend the interview (working shifts). However I was late on the Thursday accidentally and decided to not go for the interview on the Friday.

I was expecting the company to tell me to do one, however they moved the interview to the following week for me, despite me cocking them around and I was hired.

As I always say:
If they really want you, they will get you.